# Casual wedding greetings for friends

Tags: greetings

I wanted to greet my friends for their wedding. I suppose it would go something like this:

“Wishing you a lifetime of love and happiness!”

How would the japanese translation go? “... ご結婚お幸せに！”

Anybody who could lend a hand please?

Answer (score 3):

"結婚おめでとう、末永くお幸せに！" maybe better!